# Como converter imagens jpg para webp usando php?

Tags: php, jpg, webp

Estou montando um site de uma imobiliaria que importa as fotos de um xml.

Eu queria que ao importar, ele convertesse o jpg para webp, porém dos que eu encontrei na net, não consegui fazer funcionar.

Alguém sabe um jeito bom de fazer essa conversão de jpg para webp, usando o php?

Obrigado!

Comment: Leandro da uma olhada na função [imagewebp()](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagewebp.php) do próprio **PHP**

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o ImageMagick com PHP para esta tarefa, mas o suporte nativo ao webp talvez não esteja pronto.

Para garantir isso instale a biblioteca `libwebp-dev`, no Ubuntu:

`sudo apt install libwebp-dev`

#### Compilando o ImageMagick no Ubuntu 18.04

```
cd /tmp
mkdir imagemagick
cd imagemagick
wget https://www.imagemagick.org/download/ImageMagick.tar.gz
tar xvzf ImageMagick.tar.gz

sudo apt-get build-dep imagemagick
sudo apt-get install libwebp-dev devscripts
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
apt-get source imagemagick
cd ImageMagick-*

./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig /usr/local/lib

magick -version
```

#### Instalando extensão Imagick no PHP 7.2

```
sudo pecl install imagick
```

Ao instalar a extensão imagick no PHP ela virá com suporte ao webp do ImageMagick já instalado em seu sistema. Confirme o suporte ao webp em `phpinfo()`

#### Convertendo `jpg` para `webp`

```php
$image = new Imagick('/caminho/para/seu/arquivo.jpg');
$image->setImageFormat('webp');
$image->writeImage('/caminho/para/seu/arquivo.webp');
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode ser usado também o [WebP](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/).

No **CENTOS 6.10** foi necessário os seguintes passos:

```
yum install gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel    
yum install libjpeg-devel libpng-devel libtiff-devel libgif-devel
```

Ter o `gcc`, `make` e `automake`

```
cd /opt        
wget https://storage.googleapis.com/downloads.webmproject.org/releases/webp/libwebp-1.0.2.tar.gz    
tar xvzf libwebp-1.0.2.tar.gz    
cd libwebp-1.0.2
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

O [cwebp](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/cwebp) e [dwebp](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/dwebp) , foram disponibilizados no diretório  `/usr/local/bin/`, para utilizar como command no php foi necessário:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
mv cwebp /usr/bin/
mv dwebp /usr/bin/
```

No **PHP** foi usado o [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exec.php):

```
<?php
$imgName    =   "php.jpg";
$webPName   =   "php.webp";

if(file_exists($imgName)){
    exec("cwebp -q 80 $imgName -o $webPName");    
}
```

[Compilando com outras plataformas.](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/compiling)

Comment: Eu queria apenas sugerir que use `escapeshellcmd` e `escapeshellarg`. Pelo menos, no minimo, indique que o `$imgName` e `$webPName` não deve ser manipulado pelo usuário final, embora isto não corrija definitivamente. Isso pode ser óbvio para alguns, mas não para todos os futuros leitores.

Comment: @Inkeliz, sugestão totalmente válida, a ideia foi sugerir mais uma possibilidade para somar com a contribuição do Lucas e do Samuel.